# How to replace background image on scroll with animation or parallax effect

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to replace background image on scroll. I have used react-parallax but it is adding effect in another component not replacing the background image. I want to replace the bg image added by a styled component

```
  const ImgContainer = styled("div")({
    width: "100%",
    // height: "100vh",
    backgroundImage: `url(${ElHogarBg})`,
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    position: "relative",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "column",
    zIndex: "1",
  });
```

This is my styled component. I want to replace my image with parallax effect on scroll.